# _dataSourceName for SMS activity in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I'm trying to create a SMS activity in Journey Builder and use the entry source (data extension) name in the ampscript. Is this even possible?

This is the ampscript

```
%%[
set @dataSourceName = AttributeValue("_DataSourceName")
]%%

%%=v(@dataSourceName)=%% # Prints 'Preview'
```

The above code prints out 'Preview' instead of the actual entry source name

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not. In fact, it's not even possible to retrieve the data source name from an email (using `_DataSourceName` system string), as it will return 'All Subscribers' as the value. I've exhausted all options, including retrieving the Journey configuration payload from the REST API, but you won't find it in there either.

The only solution would be to store the DE name in a field in your event entry source (perhaps as a default value), or get a script activity in an Automation to populate the field based on the DE name.

Comment: I have been able to get `_DataSourceName` to work in emails, but yes, I have not had success in SMS messages.

Comment: @Gortonington are you sure you got this to work for emails sent from a Journey?